# Format USB Disk Using DiskPart Yields "No volume selected" Error

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, usb, partitioning, diskpart

I use the following `diskpart.exe` sequence. I want to specify the disk number and then format the disk.

```
C:\>diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.18362.1

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: AAAAAAA

DISKPART> select disk 2

Disk 2 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> clean

DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk.

DISKPART> create partition primary

DiskPart succeeded in creating the specified partition.

DISKPART> format fs=ntfs label="My USB Disk" quick

There is no volume selected.
Please select a volume and try again.

DISKPART>
```

As you can see, the script should work and might on `Windows 7`, as several pages searched on the internet says that, but on my `Windows 10` installation I get

> There is no volume selected

This [article](https://superuser.com/questions/957593/windows-8-1-cannot-format-partition-as-ntfs-there-are-no-volumes) does not apply. The author really did forget the `create primary partition`. Ditto [here](https://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/349587-disk-partition-has-no-volume-annoying.html).

As you can see from this screenshot, there definitely is a volume on Disk 2.

[image: diskpart showing a single volume]

My USB flash drive has a single volume, so `format` should work.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is almost correct, but here is the fragment that is missing.
Modify it according to your needs.

```
create partition primary
select partition 1
active
format fs=ntfs label="My USB Disk" quick
assign letter=D
```

Comment: After "active" it says "The selected disk is not a fixed MBR disk. The ACTIVE command can only be used on fixed MBR disks." What to do?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain: Create a new post with all the information about your setup.

Comment: Getting `no volume selected` on the `format` command.

Comment: Nope didn't work here

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue, and for the record, it worked after a reboot (it wouldn't let go of the disk to format it) and trying in CMD rather than Powershell. This worked:

1. Run CMD
2. Type "diskpart" and hit enter
3. In the diskpart window, type "list disk" and hit enter
4. Note the disk number of your USB device to use later
5. Type "sel dis 1" changing out the number 1 for whatever number your USB device was in step 4. Hit enter
6. Type "clean" and hit enter
7. Type "cre par pri size=30000" and hit enter
8. Type "sel par 1" and hit enter
9. Type "active" and hit enter
10. Type "format fs=fat32 quick" and hit enter
11. Type "assign" and hit enter
12. Close the diskpart and CMD windows.

I'm trying to prepare a 50+GB USB stick as a <32GB FAT32 partitioned boot device.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me - leaving out the `size=30000` to create the partition as the full usb size :)

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what i did but it works.

**

```
DISKPART> list disk
  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          119 GB  1024 KB        *
  Disk 1    Online          931 GB   300 GB        *
  Disk 2    Online           29 GB    29 GB
DISKPART> select disk 2
Disk 2 is now the selected disk.
DISKPART> clean
DiskPart has encountered an error: The device is not ready.
See the System Event Log for more information.
DISKPART> clean
DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk.
DISKPART> active
There is no partition selected.
Please select a partition and try again.
DISKPART> list disk
  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          119 GB  1024 KB        *
  Disk 1    Online          931 GB   300 GB        *
* Disk 2    Online           29 GB      0 B
DISKPART> select disk 2
Disk 2 is now the selected disk.
DISKPART> clean
DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk.
DISKPART> active
There is no partition selected.
Please select a partition and try again.
DISKPART> format fs=fat32 quick
There is no volume selected.
Please select a volume and try again.
DISKPART>
C:\WINDOWS\system32>diskpart
Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.22000.653
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: ZMBBY
DISKPART> list disk
  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          119 GB  1024 KB        *
  Disk 1    Online          931 GB   300 GB        *
  Disk 2    Online           29 GB    29 GB
DISKPART> select disk 2
Disk 2 is now the selected disk.
DISKPART> clean
DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk.
DISKPART> format fs=fat32 quick
There is no volume selected.
Please select a volume and try again.
DISKPART> list disk
  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          119 GB  1024 KB        *
  Disk 1    Online          931 GB   300 GB        *
  Disk 2    Online           29 GB    29 GB
DISKPART> select disk 2
Disk 2 is now the selected disk.
DISKPART> clean
DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk.
DISKPART> create partition primary
Virtual Disk Service error:
The object is not found.
DISKPART>
C:\WINDOWS\system32>diskpart
Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.22000.653
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: ZMBBY
DISKPART> list diskc
Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.22000.653
DISK        - Display a list of disks. For example, LIST DISK.
PARTITION   - Display a list of partitions on the selected disk.
              For example, LIST PARTITION.
VOLUME      - Display a list of volumes. For example, LIST VOLUME.
VDISK       - Displays a list of virtual disks.
DISKPART> list dick
Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.22000.653
DISK        - Display a list of disks. For example, LIST DISK.
PARTITION   - Display a list of partitions on the selected disk.
              For example, LIST PARTITION.
VOLUME      - Display a list of volumes. For example, LIST VOLUME.
VDISK       - Displays a list of virtual disks.
DISKPART> list disk
  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          119 GB  1024 KB        *
  Disk 1    Online          931 GB   300 GB        *
  Disk 2    Online           29 GB      0 B
DISKPART> select disk 2
Disk 2 is now the selected disk.
DISKPART> clean
DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk.
DISKPART> create partition primary
Virtual Disk Service error:
The object is not found.
DISKPART> active
There is no partition selected.
Please select a partition and try again.
DISKPART> format fs=fat32 quick
There is no volume selected.
Please select a volume and try again.
DISKPART> create partition primary size=30000
No usable free extent could be found. It may be that there is insufficient
free space to create a partition at the specified size and offset. Specify
different size and offset values or don't specify either to create the
maximum sized partition. It may be that the disk is partitioned using the MBR disk
partitioning format and the disk contains either 4 primary partitions, (no
more partitions may be created), or 3 primary partitions and one extended
partition, (only logical drives may be created).
DISKPART> create partition primary
C:\WINDOWS\system32>diskpart
Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.22000.653
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: ZMBBY
DISKPART> list disk
  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          119 GB  1024 KB        *
  Disk 1    Online          931 GB   300 GB        *
  Disk 2    Online           29 GB      0 B
DISKPART> select disk 2
Disk 2 is now the selected disk.
DISKPART> clean
DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk.
DISKPART> create partition primary
DiskPart succeeded in creating the specified partition.
DISKPART> format fs=fat32 quick
    0 percent completed
DiskPart has encountered an error: The request is not supported.
See the System Event Log for more information.
DISKPART> format fs=fat32 quick
  100 percent completed
DiskPart successfully formatted the volume.
```

**

Answer (score 0):

Hey volume is nothing much, you just have to select the drive, in my case it was H drive, which is 8th one, so I selected it and continued!

hey below is the image of my cmd process, be sure to check it out

Hope it helps:
[image: cmd process image]